# How to show next cell value when one cell is clicked in Datagridview in Messagebox

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, messagebox

I need to get the value of the next cell when one cell is clicked in vb.net.For example

ID  |               **NAME**       |         AGE

1   |               **Azleef**        |       20

2     |             **Saeed**      |        22

3      |            **Jimmy**      |        23

For example if I press **Azleef** I need the next cell. The corresponding age which is 20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the functionality you want by relying on the `CellClick` event. Sample code for `DataGridView1`:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick

    If (e.ColumnIndex > -1 AndAlso e.RowIndex > -1 AndAlso e.ColumnIndex + 1 <= DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1) Then

        Dim cell As DataGridViewCell = DataGridView1(e.ColumnIndex + 1, e.RowIndex)
        If (cell.Value IsNot Nothing) Then MessageBox.Show(cell.Value.ToString())

    End If

End Sub
```

This code works with every column (except, logically, with the last one); you have to adapt it to work just with the column(s) you wish.

Comment: What is the "e" here? What does it do?

Comment: @AhmedFaizan Do you know how to deal with events in VB.NET at all? This is one of the arguments of the `CellClick` event of the DataGridView (but all the events have the two arguments `e` and `sender`). Just write this code and will work (you have to adapt the `Handles DataGridView1.CellClick` part to the name of your datagridview if it is not `DataGridView1`).

Comment: @AhmedFaizan You are welcome (don't feel offended; I am a bit direct some times, but my intention is always helping).